# "Other user" appears multiple times on Win10 lock screen

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login-screen

Usually, on the Windows 10 lock screen on the bottom left, there's a clickable 'Other user' button to choose to login to another user than the current user who locked it.  I'm seeing two instances of the 'Other user' button and NOT seeing the name of the current user.  Where in Windows 10 can I control this behavior?

Comment: Is the current user literally 'Other user' maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This process worked for me after I had to re-image my company laptop:

1. Open Start -> Run -> `secpol.msc` to open the Local Security Policy control panel.
2. Navigate to `Local Policies -> Security Options`.
3. Set `Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in` and `Interactive logon: Don't display username at sign-in` to `Disabled`.
4. Close the control panel.
5. Open an administrator command window.
6. Run `gpupdate /force` (You may need to connect to VPN if this is a company group policy.)
7. Test by locking/unlocking Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a domain-joined Windows 10 system, there will be an “Other user” option on the lock-screen. For a workgroup Windows 10 system, available local user name(s) will be displayed on the lock-screen.

1. Run “sfc /scannow” to check/repair system files.
2. Create a new user account, or use another domain credential to log on and log out.
3. If the problem does not happen on the new/other account, we may try to re-create your problematic user profile.